# Error running spark action in oozie: User: root is not allowed to impersonate root

Tags: oozie

I have installed oozie-4.2 on AWS as root and am running the workflow as root as well.I have hadoop-2.4 running on a cluster

I have added the following in oozie-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
</property>
```

In addition my hadoop core-site.xml also has the following:

```
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>

  <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
  </property>
```

After the config changes above, I stopped hdfs/yarn and restarted them. When I start oozied, I get these warnings

```
2016-02-03 07:12:22,987  WARN ConfigurationService:523 - SERVER[]
Invalid configuration defined,
[oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.root.groups] 
2016-02-03 07:12:22,987  WARN ConfigurationService:523 - SERVER[]
Invalid configuration defined, 
[oozie.service.ProxyUserService.proxyuser.root.hosts]
```

When I start spark action based workflow, I get these errors :

```
Message [JA002: User: root is not allowed to impersonate root]
org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutorException: JA002: User: root is not allowed to impersonate root
at 

org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertExceptionHelper(ActionExecutor.java:462)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.ActionExecutor.convertException(ActionExecutor.java:436)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.submitLauncher(JavaActionExecutor.java:1132)
    at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.JavaActionExecutor.start(JavaActionExecutor.java:1286)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:250)
    at org.apache.oozie.command.wf.ActionStartXCommand.execute(ActionStartXCommand.java:64)
    at org.apache.oozie.comma
```

Can someone pl help with what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: I believe your 1st sentence is explicit: you are running Oozie under service-user `root`, and using it to start Linux processes for end-user `root`. it's not exactly a "wrong" thing to do, rather an "evil" thing to do. Hadoop has a few sanity checks to prevent these evil things to happen.